# PC based wifi hotpsot management

Tags: hotspot

I have got an ADSL internet connection with wireless tp link modem and a PC with Windows 7 OS. I would like to set up voucher based hotspot management system on this PC. Do I also need a wireless router with specialized firmware flashed into it in order to set up the system? Is it possible to set it up using my PC by making it act as a server by installing some hotpsot management application on it instead of flashing any specialized firmware on the router?

Thanks.

Comment: anyone out there?